# Add onclick event via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following lines of code in my web page:

```
<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev" aria-label="previous" style="display: block;">Previous</button>

<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next" aria-label="next" style="display: block;">Next</button>
```

The *previous* and *next* buttons are placed in to the web page via a number of *external* files - [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), which is stored on another server and included within the `<head>` tags.

I need to place two separate counters on to each of these buttons for when they are clicked by the user.

As I can't modify the external JavaScript file, how can I add the following code to either one of the buttons which will execute the counters?

```
onclick="myCounter()"

onclick="myCounterTwo()"
```

The buttons should then resemble this:

```
<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev" aria-label="previous" style="display: block;" onclick="myCounter()">Previous</button>

<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next" aria-label="next" style="display: block;" onclick="myCounterTwo()">Next</button>
```

Comment: you can't access the full javascript file?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. In one paragraph, you say that you can't modify the JavaScript. In another, you say that you tried modifying the JavaScript.

Comment: Why the **** are you combining JavaScript and jQuery?

Comment: i think you should ask yourself what you really want to see as solution. all the suggests are correct and possible even without touching your existing script file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#my-id').slick({
        prevArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev" aria-label="previous" onclick="prevCall()">Previous</button>',
        nextArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next" aria-label="next" onclick="nextCall()">Next</button>',
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you can use jQuery since it's one of your tag :

Do you have a good reason to use the onclick attribute ?

It's way better to bind an event using the function `on()` (jQuery)

ex :

```
$(document).on('click', '.slick-next', myCounterTwo)
```

If you can't edit your JS files (which is very strange if you must work with HTML...) you can still add a script tag after your buttons... It's ugly but less than using onclick attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in **HTML** like:

```
<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev" aria-label="previous" 
        style="display: block;" onclick="myCounter()">Previous</button>
<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next" aria-label="next" 
        style="display: block;" onclick="myCounterTwo()">Next</button>
```

Or in **jQuery** like:

```
$(".slick-prev").click(function () {
  myCounter();
});
$(".slick-next").click(function () {
  myCounterTwo();
});
```

And in **JavaScript** like:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(".slick-prev")[0].click = myCounter;
document.getElementsByClassName(".slick-next")[0].click = myCounterTwo;
```

Or by **delegating** in **JavaScript**:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(".slick-prev")[0].addEventListener("click", myCounter, false);
document.getElementsByClassName(".slick-next")[0].addEventListener("click", myCounterTwo, false);
```

You can use the possible method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in jQuery environment.
So you add a custom binding to the click event!

You can add this as separate script block in your markup (i.e after your buttons) if you can't change your other js file.

```
<script>
$('.slick-prev').on('click', myCounter);

        function myCounter() {
           // your code
        }
</script>
```

Comment: It does because you can add this script block also to your markup after your buttons!

Comment: Yup, with the script tags it does. I deleted my comment.